# Session not holding $_POST values

Tags: html, forms, session, php

This is a little hard to explain.. Using pictures probably helps!
**1.** The user submits the form, easy.
 [image]
**2.** The session is being set and displays the session variables that have been set.
[image]
**3.** If the user enters the CAPTCHA incorrectly or they get it correct and it continues to the next page, the *inp_name*, *inp_username* and *inp_email* session values disappear. The *inp_password* value remains (but it is becoming encrypted, md5(), when the session value is set. 
[image]

**THE FORM:**

```html
<form action="./" method="post" class="form-300">

    <div class="title top">Full Name</div>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$_POST['name'] ?>" />

    <div class="title top">Username</div>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?=$_POST['username'] ?>" />

    <div class="title top">Email</div>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?=$_POST['email'] ?>" />

    <div class="title top">Password</div>
    <input type="password" name="password" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" />
    <div class="tc">By clicking Sign Up, you agree to the Terms of Use, Privacy Policy and that you are or over the age of 13.</div>
    <span class="sep-text">or</span>
    <a href="./?action=fb" class="btn-300 btn-fb">Sign Up using Facebook</a>
    <br /><br /><br />
</form>
```

**THE CAPTCHA:**

```php
<?php ob_start(); if(session_id() != 'uv241112'){
session_name("uv241112"); session_start();
    $_SESSION['inp_isset'] = "eAK28";
    $_SESSION['inp_name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['inp_username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['inp_email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['inp_password'] = md5($_POST['password']);
}else{ session_name("uv241112"); session_start(); } ?>
        <form action="./" method="post">
        <?php

        require_once('../resources/recaptchalib.php'); $publickey = "xxxxxxxxxx"; $privatekey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        # the response from reCAPTCHA
        $resp = null;
        # the error code from reCAPTCHA, if any
        $error = null;

        if ($_POST["submit_recaptcha"]) {
                $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

                if ($resp->is_valid) {
                        echo "You got it!";
                } else {
                        ?><div class="alert alert-error alert-440">Sorry, the text you entered was incorrect.</div><?php
                        # set the error code so that we can display it
                        $error = $resp->error;
                }
        }
        echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
        ?>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit_recaptcha" value="Check" class="btn-300 btn-green" />
            </form>

            <?php echo $_SESSION['inp_name']; ?>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['inp_username']; ?>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['inp_email']; ?>
            <?php echo $_SESSION['inp_password']; ?>

<?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: What does the next page look like?  That seems to be the one causing the issues.

Comment: Do you mean the design or how the page is coded?

Comment: Coding, of course.  I apologize that my question seems to be looking for aesthetics. ^^

Comment: Keep in mind, a quality code formatting strategy is critical in spotting inconsistencies and errors in code. You could easily have a rotten easter egg that was obvious if your code followed some coding style guide, but who knows. I suggest checking out [PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/) for guidance.

Comment: `session_id()` and `session_name()` are not the same thing but your code appears to think they are.

Comment: The actual problem with the code is that you set the session variables at the top of the page based on POST values.  After it was submitted the first time, that works, but submitting the second time you aren't POSTing those values again, and therefore setting your session variables to empty. (The password is still showing because it's the MD5 of a blank line.  If you compare the MD5 values, you'll see they're different to confirm that)

Comment: Ah, okay. But then, why does the _inp_password_ stay?

Comment: (The password is still showing because it's the MD5 of a blank line. If you compare the MD5 values, you'll see they're different to confirm that) -- sorry, tried to edit the other comment quickly enough to add this.

Comment: That means the solution would be to check the `$_SESSION` variables and use those if they exist, or not to reset the session variables if the `$_POST` variables are empty.

Comment: I'll have a go at cleaning up my code and I'll see if that works. Thanks everyone. :)

Comment: I still do not get the reason for the first if condition. What is your intention when you set the session name? What do you expect from it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going about checking for a form submission the wrong way. You shouldn't be seeing if a session name exists yet. In fact, you should have already started a session in every case.

Session_start() should be the first thing on each page.

As for your post values, you should be validating and using a hidden form value to determine what page they have submitted. For example:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="hidden" name="emailpage" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="send" value="send">
</form>
```

Then to check the form

```
<?php
    Session_start();
    If (!empty($_POST['emailpage'])) {
        // do variable validation
        $_SESSION['email'] = $validatedemail;
    }
```

There is no need for a conditional statement session_start. There also is likely no need to be setting session name.

Code posted is sample code posted from cell phone, so may be issues.

Answer (score 0):

A question about session_id and session_name.  I noticed you're setting session_name prior to session start.  I was wondering why you test for session_id, instead of session_name?

```
--> ... if(session_id() != 'uv241112'){
                    session_name("uv241112"); ...
```

Perhaps it should be

```
--> ... if(session_name() != 'uv241112'){
                    session_name("uv241112"); ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> The actual problem with the code is that you set the session variables at the top of the page based on POST values. After it was submitted the first time, that works, but submitting the second time you aren't POSTing those values again, and therefore setting your session variables to empty. (The password is still showing because it's the MD5 of a blank line. If you compare the MD5 values, you'll see they're different to confirm that)

Quoting myself from the comments for the those don't care to read them before down-voting again

To make it easier to see what to change...

```
$_SESSION['inp_isset'] = "eAK28";
$_SESSION['inp_name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['inp_username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['inp_email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['inp_password'] = md5($_POST['password']);
```

To:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) {
    $_SESSION['inp_isset'] = "eAK28";
    $_SESSION['inp_name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $_SESSION['inp_username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['inp_email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['inp_password'] = md5($_POST['password']);
}
```

And that would be a somewhat crude example, but only because the code does need to be cleaned up a bit. ^^

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the down rate?  If you are going to down-rate an answer, the least you can do is put why you don't think the solution is viable. But, because of that...I put my explanation here as well from the comments on the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but !isset($_POST['username']) happens when no post has occured meaning the result is still undesired.

Comment: Not true, it checks the 'username' post, not the entire array, so if the problem was the captcha not working, and all that is being submitted again is the captcha, `$_POST['username']` will not be set, however `$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"]` would still be set, so it is a valid test.  (If `$_POST['username']` is set, then he wouldn't be running in to the issue of the the session be cleared.)

Comment: Read your own code one more time. Let's say post['username'] is not set. So isset would be false. So !false would be true. So that conditional evaluates true when the username var is not set. That means you are assigning session values with variables that are not set which is not only wrong but will cause notices.

Comment: Aye.  You are right.  I first wrote the code checking for the session value instead of post and forgot to remove the not operator. Fixed in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I re-coded the file, cleaned it up a lot, it didn't work. But I put the following code in a new file and went to it after submitting the form. It worked. So I'll just work off the new file, if that makes sense. Thanks everyone for your help, greatly appreciated.

```
session_name("uv241112"); session_start();
echo $_SESSION['inp_name'];
echo $_SESSION['inp_username'];
echo $_SESSION['inp_email'];
echo $_SESSION['inp_password'];
```

Comment: Your not helping youself with this one and you are also not helping any future user who views this question. Consider reviewing my comment and revising your code to a more standardized method.